# AngularJS dropdown not showing selected value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs, ng-options

Am facing problem in displaying selected value in angular dropdown.
it works when i give like this

```
$scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[1];
```

not working, if i give directly that value

```
$scope.selectedItem = { name: 'two', age: 27 };
```

**HTML**:

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="Test">
      <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="item.name for item in items">
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**JS**:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('Test',function($scope){
   $scope.items = [{name: 'one', age: 30 },{ name: 'two', age: 27 },{ name: 'three', age: 50 }];
  $scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[1];
});
```

**CODEPEN:**
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zxXpmR

**SOLUTION:**

Thank you samir-das. I fixed as per your suggestion.

```
var choosen_value = { name: 'two', age: 27 };
angular.forEach($scope.items, function(item){
  if(angular.equals(choosen_value, item)){
    $scope.selectedItem = item;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, because

`$scope.items[1]` and `{ name: 'two', age: 27 }` is totally different thing.

`{ name: 'two', age: 27 }` is a totally different object whereas `$scope.items[1]` is part of the object `$scope.items`

When you put something in the template using `{{}}`, angular add it in its watcher list.

SO when angular put it in the watch list, it was an object (i.e. `{ name: 'two', age: 27 }` ) that is different than `$scope.items`.

`selectedItem` is attached with the object that you set in the controller. In summary   while dirty checking, angular will checks `selectedItem` against  `{ name: 'two', age: 27 }` NOT against `$scope.items`

Hope you understand what I mean

Comment: Do you have any way to fix this?

Comment: You will have to use same object. You can search the item first by which one you want to start, then assign that found item

Answer (score 7):

As explained in the other answers, while the two objects may have the same properties and values, they are two different objects so angular doesn't consider them to be equal.

You can however use the `track by` expression in [ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) to specify a property which will decide equality:

`ng-options="item.name for item in items track by item.name"`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WbWMrp

Answer (score 1):

This is **not** an Angular feature/issue, it is a consequence of how object equality works in Javascript. [This article](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/finding-array-elements-with-array-indexof.html) does a fairly good job in explaining what is going on in a pretty concise way and gives some examples. Check out the source of [lodash's isEqual method](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/3.6.0/lodash.src.js#L8556) (it will take you to the definition of `baseIsEqualDeep` eventually) to see how what you are trying to achieve can be done in pure JS.

In any case, I do not think there is an easy way to achieve this in Angular, you would have to re-write the way `ng-options` works and you probably do not want to go there...

Answer (score 1):

In angular, Arrays and objects are passed by reference while strings, numbers and booleans are passed by value. So, angular interprets `$scope.items[1]` and `{ name: 'two', age: 27 }` as two different objects. That's why your binding fails when you do `$scope.selectedItem = { name: 'two', age: 27 };` directly and find it in '$scope.items'.