# Select not displaying its default value

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-select

I have a `select` for which the value is a simple object.

The content displayed as an `option` is a property of this object but the value is the object itself.

I'm setting a default value for this `select` by setting the model to the proper object.

But the `select` doesn't show any value selected, while the model is properly set.

Here are 3 different ways I tried :

```
Current value of representative.title : {{representative.title}} <br/><br />
<div class="form-group">
  <select ng-model="representative.title" 
          ng-options="title.name for title in titles" 
          ng-disabled="$parent.isDisabled" 
          class="form-control">
  </select>
</div>

<br />

<div class="form-group">
  <select ng-model="representative.title" 
          class="form-control">
    <option ng-repeat="title in titles" 
            value="{{title}}">
              {{title.name}}
    </option>
  </select>
</div>

<br />

<div class="form-group">
  <select ng-model="representative.title" 
          ng-options="title as title.name for title in titles" 
          ng-disabled="$parent.isDisabled" 
          class="form-control">

  </select>
</div>
```

And in my controller :

```
$scope.titles = [{"name": "Monsieur"},{"name": "Madame"}];
$scope.representative = {"title": {"name": "Monsieur"}, "otherField": "otherValue"};
```

Why isn't my select showing the default value ?

How can I fix it ?

(Btw, I'm using Angular 1.2.28)

Comment: ___`{} !== {}`___

Comment: possible answer here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29407513/angularjs-dropdown-not-showing-selected-value

Comment: May be `ng-options` with `label as` may help you...

Comment: I'm using the `as` in my third case. The problem comes more likely from the fact that the objects are similar but have a different reference I think. I'm gonna explore this

Comment: Yes, I did this $scope.representative.title=$scope.titles[0]; and it worked...may be angular is not considering $scope.representative.title as type of title[i].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$scope.representative = {"title": $scope.titles[0], "otherField": "otherValue"};`

It would be more accurate as you need to pass the reference of one of the object contained in your options array.

Comment: Yea I think that's the issue here. But `title` is actually set from a service, so I would need to do a little treatment on it to make it equal to an index of `titles`, that's what I'm gonna try now

Comment: Yes that was it, it's working when we pass it as a reference (except for the second select which is probably not a good way to do it in angular)